# Does Screaming Bow's daily power affect the triggering attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, weapons

My DM is saying that the power on Screaming Bow which gives vulnerable 5 thunder does not apply to the attack which allows the power to activate.  Is this the case?

For reference:

> Power (daily): Free action.
>   Trigger: You hit an enemy with this weapon.
>   Effect: That enemy gains vulnerable 5 thunder (save ends).

And the property:

> When you use this weapon to hit an enemy with an attack power that doesn't deal typed damage, that attack deals thunder damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **RAW** :

A free action with a trigger falls in the category "Other Triggered effects" : it isn't an immediate action nor an opportunity attack (which both occur during someone else's turn).

In the rules compendium :

> If an effect has a trigger but is neither an immediate action nor an opportunity action, assume that it behaves like an immediate reaction, **waiting for its trigger to completely resolve**. However, ignore this guideline when the effect has to interrupt its trigger to function. For instance, if a triggered power allows an adventurer to use a free action to reroll an attack roll, with the hope of turning a miss into a hit, the power must interrupt the trigger ("You miss with an attack") to function: otherwise the attack would be resolved as a miss.

*Source : p. 195 & 196 of the Rules Compendium (emphasis mine).*

As we're not in the case of "has to interrupt its trigger to function", the free action resolves after its trigger.

In short : your DM is right.

Answer (score 3):

**Your DM is right.**

Because the daily power is triggered by a *hit*, it is delivered along *with* the other effects of that hit (like the damage), **not** *before* those effects. And because the target wasn't vulnerable when you damaged them, they do not take extra damage from the vulnerability.

To put it another way, since the damage & the vulnerability have the same trigger (the hit), why do you think the vulnerability would happen *before* the damage?